# How to stop all process of specific apache?

Tags: kill, centos-7, httpd

I use CentOS and have running multiple instances of httpd, example:

```
/usr/sbin/httpd
/opt/zimbra/httpd/bin/httpd
```

But need kill all process only /usr/sbin/httpd

```
killall -9 -v httpd
```

Kill all httpd include the zimbra httpd, i need stop only /usr/sbin/httpd. systemctl stop httpd.service is very very slow.

Comment: `pgrep`/`pkill`: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify the full path of your httpd

```
killall -9 -v /usr/sbin/httpd
```

Comment: Process not found. ps -aux | grep httpd
    ... /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
    killall -9 -v /usr/sbin/httpd
    /usr/sbin/httpd process not found.
    ls -la /usr/sbin/httpd
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 637528 ene 14 14:46 /usr/sbin/httpd